# How do I assert .containsText with case insensitive in Nightwatch.js?

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

How do I assert .`containsText` with case insensitive in `Nightwatch.js`?
For example I search for '`odin` sphere' on google.
There are a lot of possibilities for the search result, like  'Odin Sphere' 'odin sphere' 'ODIN SPHERE' etc etc I would like to assert with just 'odin sphere'.
Here's the code I wrote.

````
module.exports = {
    beforeEach: browser => {
        browser.url('https://www.google.com/')
    },
    after: browser => {
        browser.end()
    },
    'Search test': browser => {
        browser
            .setValue('input[name="q"]',['odin sphere',browser.Keys.ENTER])
            .waitForElementVisible('#res')
            .pause(5000)
            .verify.containsText('#res','Odin Sphere')
    }

}```

Thanks in advance!
````

Answer (score -1):

https://nightwatchjs.org/api/#assert-containsText

Usage:

```
this.demoTest = function (browser) {
  browser.assert.containsText("#main", "The Night Watch");
};
```